# Как связать результат агрегатной функции со строкой в таблице при SELECT в Postgres

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, select

Вечер добрый. Не понимаю одну элементарную вещь.

Есть таблица items с совокупностью некоторых товаров.
Есть таблица variations с указанием видов товара из items. То есть на один товар из items существует несколько вариантов комплектации/расцветки в таблице variations.

В таблице variations содержатся цены на каждый вариант комплектации товара из items.

Я использую INNER JOIN чтобы связать между собой все вещи из items и одну из вариаций из variations с минимальным значением цены.

```
SELECT items.id,
MIN(variations.price),
FROM variations INNER JOIN items ON variations.items_id = items.id GROUP BY items.id ORDER BY items.id
```

Однако есть еще несколько полей, которые я хочу получить из variations для записи с минимальной ценой. Например поле discount. Вопрос в том, как мне указать Postgres то, что он должен вытащить поле discount именно из записи с минимальной ценой, которая получена из агрегатной функции MIN.

Comment: Существует ли альтернатива алиасам или что-то такое, для того чтобы получить поля именно этой записи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прошу извинения, писать по-русски мне непросто.
Результат можно получить используя замечательные выражения Postgresql `distinct on` and `order by` вместо использования агрегатных функций.

Здесь немного модифицированный ваш запрос

```sql
SELECT distinct on (items.id)
  items.id,
  variations.price,
  variations.discount
  -- maybe other fields & expressions here
FROM variations INNER JOIN items ON variations.items_id = items.id
ORDER BY items.id, variations.price;
```

Comment: You're so cool. It works, thank u :)

Answer (score 0):

Окей, мне удалось добиться желаемого результата обернув запрос в запрос. Хотя меня все еще не покидает чувство, что есть вариант проще. Но если варианта лучше не предложат, то возможно мой кому-то когда-то поможет.

```
SELECT secondary_table.items_id, secondary_table.var_price, MAX(variations.old_price) as var_old_price
    FROM variations
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT items.id as items_id,
         MIN(var_table.price) as var_price
             FROM variations var_table INNER JOIN items ON var_table.items_id = items.id 
             GROUP BY items.id ORDER BY items.id) secondary_table
    ON 
        secondary_table.var_price = variations.price AND secondary_table.items_id = 
        variations.items_id GROUP BY secondary_table.items_id, secondary_table.var_price ORDER BY secondary_table.items_id
```